# Assign a higher score to matches containing the search query at an earlier position in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram, relevance, booleanquery

This question is similar to my other question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747380/how-to-use-an-ngram-and-edge-ngram-tokenizer-together-in-elasticsearch-index/61747899?noredirect=1#comment109254691_61747899) which Val answered.

I have an index containing 3 documents.

```
    {
            "firstname": "Anne",
            "lastname": "Borg",
        }

    {
            "firstname": "Leanne",
            "lastname": "Ray"
        },

    {
            "firstname": "Anne",
            "middlename": "M",
            "lastname": "Stone"
        }
```

When I search for "Ann", I would like elastic to return all 3 of these documents (because they all match the term "Ann" to a degree). BUT, I would like Leanne Ray to have a lower score (relevance ranking) because the search term "Ann" appears at a later position in this document than the term appears in the other two documents.

Here are my index settings...

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit",
                        "custom"
                    ],
                    "custom_token_chars": "'-",
                    "min_gram": "1",
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "max_gram": "2"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "firstname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                },
                "copy_to": [
                    "full_name"
                ]
            },
            "lastname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                },
                "copy_to": [
                    "full_name"
                ]
            },
            "middlename": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                },
                "copy_to": [
                    "full_name"
                ]
            },
            "full_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following query brings back the expected documents, but attributes a higher score to Leanne Ray than to Anne Borg.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "Ann",
                    "fields": ["full_name"]
                }
            },
            "should": {
                "match": {
                    "full_name": "Ann"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results...

```
"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "contacts_4",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 6.6333585,
            "_source": {
                "firstname": "Anne",
                "middlename": "M",
                "lastname": "Stone"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "contacts_4",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 6.142234,
            "_source": {
                "firstname": "Leanne",
                "lastname": "Ray"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "contacts_4",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 6.079495,
            "_source": {
                "firstname": "Anne",
                "lastname": "Borg"
            }
        }
```

Using an ngram token filter *and* an ngram tokenizer together seems to fix this problem...

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "ngram"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "ngram"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "firstname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                },
                "copy_to": [
                    "full_name"
                ]
            },
            "lastname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                },
                "copy_to": [
                    "full_name"
                ]
            },
            "middlename": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                },
                "copy_to": [
                    "full_name"
                ]
            },
            "full_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The same query brings back the expected results with the desired relative scoring. **Why does this work?** Note that above, I am using an ngram tokenizer with a lowercase filter and the only difference here is that I am using an ngram filter instead of the lowercase filter.

Here are the results. Notice that Leanne Ray scored lower than both Anne Borg and Anne M Stone, as desired.

```
"hits": [
    {
        "_index": "contacts_4",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 4.953257,
        "_source": {
            "firstname": "Anne",
            "lastname": "Borg"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "contacts_4",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 4.87168,
        "_source": {
            "firstname": "Anne",
            "middlename": "M",
            "lastname": "Stone"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "contacts_4",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0364896,
        "_source": {
            "firstname": "Leanne",
            "lastname": "Ray"
        }
    }
```

By the way, this query also brings back a whole lot of false positive results when the index contains other documents as well. It's not such a problem becasuethese false positives have very low scores relative to the scores of the desirable hits. But still not ideal. For example, if I add {firstname: Gideon, lastname: Grossma} to the document, the above query will bring back that document in the result set as well - albeit with a much lower score than the documents containing the string "Ann"

Comment: I'm not sure I get the difference here. Can you show which results you'd like to get, in which order and why?

Comment: Okay. I just clarified the difference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the same as in the linked thread. Since you're ngraming all the indexed data, it works the same way with `Ann` as with `Anne`, You'll get the exact same response (see below), with different scores, though:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "5Jr-DHIBhYuDqANwSeiw",
    "_score" : 4.8442974,
    "_source" : {
      "firstname" : "Anne",
      "lastname" : "Borg"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "5pr-DHIBhYuDqANwSeiw",
    "_score" : 4.828779,
    "_source" : {
      "firstname" : "Anne",
      "middlename" : "M",
      "lastname" : "Stone"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "5Zr-DHIBhYuDqANwSeiw",
    "_score" : 0.12874341,
    "_source" : {
      "firstname" : "Leanne",
      "lastname" : "Ray"
    }
  }
]
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a modified query that you can use to check for parts (i.e. `ann` vs `anne`). Again, the casing makes no difference here, since the analyzer lowercases everything before indexing.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "ann",
          "fields": [
            "full_name"
          ]
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "firstname": {
              "query": "ann",
              "boost": "10"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "lastname": {
              "query": "ann",
              "boost": "10"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I realized that the index settings I was using and posting were not completely consistent. I've updated my question and included two sets of results. The first has poor scoring and uses only an ngram tokenizer. The second has great scoring and uses an ngram tokenizer in addition to an ngram token filter. I'm curious why that ngram token filter makes the difference here and also how to make unrelated documents not match at all.

Comment: As tokenizers and token filters are different, can you read this and comment again what you understood: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168764/tokenizer-vs-token-filters/37169584#37169584 I don't really see how it makes sense to use an ngram tokenizer AND token filter at the same time

Comment: It turns out this part of our query 

"should": {
                "match": {
                    "full_name": "Ann"}
            }

only helps when the search term matches the casing in the document. If we search for "ann" rather than "Ann", we would still like Anne Borg and Anne Stone to get higher scores than Leanne Ray. However, this is only the case when the user searches for "Ann".

Comment: The query you're using in your question yields the same results for both `ann` and `Ann` since the casing plays no role here because your custom analyzer lowercases every token.

Comment: I haven't tested this thoroughly enough yet to know. When I do, I will for sure mark this answer correct or comment. I diverted my attention to learning about elasticsearch's span_near and intervals queries.